# nasm ignores vstart=0x7C00 in .text section

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm, bootloader

I am using NASM 2.16.01, Arch Linux.

I try to write a boot sector (8086, IBM PC) using the `vstart=0x7C00` attribute, so that following address calculations should be relative to that.

However, it does not work, since all addresses are still calculated relative to `0`. Why is this (I do not understand the NASM documentation then)? I want the `jmp 0:$+5` in line 33 to eval to `EA xx7C 0000`.

My code:

```
     1                                  bits 16
     2                                  ; this is the boot sector which is located on every floppy
     3                                  ; it gets loaded to CS:IP = 07C00h
     4                                          section .text start=0 vstart=0x7C00
     5                                  
     6 00000000 EB3C                            jmp loader
     7 00000002 90                              nop
     8 00000003 52444F5320302E31                oem_name db "RDOS 0.1"
     9 0000000B 0002                            bytes_pro_sector dw 512
    10 0000000D 01                              sectors_per_cluster db 1
    11 0000000E 0100                            reserved_sectors dw 1
    12 00000010 02                              num_fats db 2
    13 00000011 E000                            root_entries_max dw 224
    14 00000013 400B                            num_sectors dw 2880
    15 00000015 F0                              media_desc db 0xF0
    16 00000016 0900                            sectors_per_fat dw 9
    17 00000018 1200                            secs_per_track dw 18
    18 0000001A 0200                            num_heads dw 2
    19 0000001C 000000000000000000-             reserved db 10 dup 0
    19 00000025 00                 
    20 00000026 29                              extended_bpb db 0x29
    21                                  
    22 00000027 FA0E340C                        volid dd 0x0C340EFA
    23 0000002B 4E4F204E414D452020-             volname db "NO NAME    "
    23 00000034 2020               
    24 00000036 4641543132202020                fatid db "FAT12   "
    25                                          
    26                                  loader:
    27 0000003E FA                              cli
    28 0000003F 31C0                            xor ax, ax
    29 00000041 8ED8                            mov ds, ax
    30 00000043 8EC0                            mov es, ax
    31 00000045 8ED0                            mov ss, ax      
    32 00000047 BCFF7E                          mov sp, 7EFFh    ; 256 bytes stack after this code
    33 0000004A EA[4F00]0000                    jmp 0:$+5        ; fix for BIOS that uses 7C0:0 instead of 0:7C00
```

Comment: Interestingly, `yasm -p nasm` produces exactly what I want. It seems to be a bug in nasm... the same with version 2.15.05

Comment: It appears that when you use the NASM list file option that it outputs relocations (the square brackets []) even though the output format is binary.  Obviously NASM can figure out the address in that FAR JMP when producing a binary. The binary output is likely correct. You can run `ndisasm -b16 -o 0x7c00 boot.bin` to see the fully resolved binary where `boot.bin` is the name of the binary you generated with NASM.

Comment: @MichaelPetch OMG you are right. The listing from nasm does not show the real binary data... The listing from yasm however does. I also verified with `hexdump -C`, where I can see the correct jump address. So I will use yasm now, because the listing should clearly show the bytes emitted to the binary and not something else... So it is not a bug, it is just completely useless output in my case...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @MichaelPetch pointed out (thanks!) `nasm` shows relocatable addresses in its code listing with `[]`, so

```
33 0000004A EA[4F00]0000                    jmp 0:$+5
```

Is indeed encoded `EA 4F 7C 00 00` within the binary that is generated. (Checked with `hexdump -C`)

The listing that is generated by using `yasm -p nasm` however
does not show square brackets and directly shows the correct binary data that also is stored in the binary file. (As one would expect).

Hence the relocatable binary data which `nasm` displays is misleading, because a binary file does not have a relocation table.